# MediaPlayer SeekTo method not working

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, wav

I am playing a .wav file using `MediaPlayer`. **It's bitrate is 64kbps.** It plays fine but when I use `seekTo` method of `MediaPlayer` through `SeekBar` it shows strange behavior, it runs farther than seekTo position. What can be the problem?
 I used .mp3 file in place of .wav file and `seekTo` feature is working fine. **Bitrate of .mp3 file is 256kbps.**

Comment: can you post your code please  :)

Comment: I took the code from [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) url...It works for .mp3.

Comment: Another strange behavior I noticed is, this is common problem in all emulators and can be reproduced in some old devices having Android 2.2.